# How to properly set custom window maxsize on secondary screen to not overlap taskbar?

Tags: wpf, winapi

I have two screens: primary is *1920x1080* and secondary is *2560x1440*. I have a WPF window with *WindowStyle=None*. By default it overlaps the taskbar when maximized. So that my window doesn't overlap the taskbar, I add a hook to the window and modify *ptMaxSize* and *ptMaxPosition* of [MINMAXINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagminmaxinfo) structure according to screen's workarea.

It works great with the primary screen, but there's a problem with the secondary screen. Window manager for some reason 'adjusts' *ptMaxSize* value as described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150501-00/?p=44964) (values that are smaller than primary screen's size are leaved as is, values that are equal or bigger are multiplied in such way that value equal to the primary screen's size corresponds to the secondary screen's size). Because of this behavior I can't set values that are bigger than the primary screen's size but smaller than the secondary screen's size.

How do I set values in this range, so that my window occupies entire work area of my secondary screen (not overlapping the taskbar)?

Comment: Have you read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297721/restrict-window-maximum-size-in-secondary-monitor)?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT unfortunately, there's suggestion to do just what I've already tried - to set ptMaxSize and ptMaxPosition according to monitor's work area.